# Generating Heatmaps from pixel coordinates

Tags: python, opencv, plot

I have a set of pixel values that I wanted to map on an image as a heatmap. My pixel values look something like this: they are x,y coordinates of image pixels of an arbitrary resolution.

```
pixel values = [[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[2,1]]
```

I have tried using OpenCV but I fail to understand how to get it to work. I assume a probability/density distribution needs to be generated, or perhaps the plotting function can do this automatically ? Since the image is loaded using OpenCV, I was looking for an OpenCV function, if Matplotlib works, please do comment.

```
heatmap_array = np.array(heatmap)
cv_colormap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap_array[0:], cv2.COLORMAP_HOT)
cv2.imwrite("colormap_gen.jpg", cv_colormap)
```

There needs to be an slightly opaque overlay of the heatmap on top of the original image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with Matplotlib:

```
# sample data
# xy can be np.array(pixel_values)
np.random.seed(1)
xy = np.random.multivariate_normal([300,300], [[2000,400],[400,1000]], 2000000)

# compute the hist
# bins here are the size of the image
hist,_,_ = np.histogram2d(xy[:,0], xy[:,1], bins=(600,800))

# show heatmap by plt
# you can use plt to save the figure
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.imshow(hist,cmap='hot')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]